# Which Eclipse to use for Android Development

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipselink, adt

I want use eclipse for Android Development and then use the ADT Plugin from Google. 
But Which eclipse to use:

Release Luna Packages:

1 - Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers

or

2- Eclipse IDE for Java and DSL Developers

thanks

Comment: Just install ADT bundle..zip file contain the required eclipse

Comment: Any Eclipse package will do. Try the standard one to start with. For Android development, you don't need DSL or Java EE components.

Comment: Any will work.  Its easiest to just use the one Google bundles so everything is set up though.

Comment: I suggest you download Android Studio. It is now officially in beta and will be the preferred development environment in the near future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to start developing for the Android Platform is to use the ADT Bundle. It is built over eclipse and comes with latest SDKs preinstalled and you need to do nothing to set it up. (Generally)

You can download it from here : http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html